# PHP - loop inside a loop for hierarchical nested questions and answers

Tags: php, loops, parent-child

I pretend to display this multidimensional array in a hierarchical structure, showing the children comments below their parents.

```
$comments = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [text] => What is the capital of Japan?
        [parent_id] => 0
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [text] => What is the capital of Canada?
        [parent_id] => 0
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [text] => I think is Kyoto
        [parent_id] => 1
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [text] => You are wrong, is Tokyo
        [parent_id] => 3
    )
```

I've searched for many answers arround here, but most of them involved several queries to DB, or an unnecesary sublevel field in array. A very simple and efficient loop function can make it run. I'm not an expert, and I'm using very basic code, but this time is not working well:

Let's issue an initial loop with a function to display only parent comments (parents have [parent_id]=0)

```
echo '<ol>';
loopComments($comments, 0);
echo '</ol>';
```

Here are the functions:

```
function loopComments($comments, $parent) {
    foreach ($comments as $post) {
        if ($post[parent_id] == $parent) {      
            printPost($post);
        }
    }
}

//The function below prints the post and searches for related answers
//sadly FAILS when looping again! 

function printPost($post) {
    echo "<li>".$post['text']."</li>";
    loopComments($comments, $post['parent_id']);
}
```

Sadly I'm getting 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() '

Answer (score 0):

In your `printPost()` function you need to have one parameter which will parse the comments variable in order to use that array inside the function

```
function printPost($post, $comments) {}
```

when you'll call it you'll have

```
function loopComments($comments, $parent) {
    foreach ($comments as $post) {
        if ($post[parent_id] == $parent) {      
            printPost($post, $comments);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in your code.

STEP:
1. Call **loopComments**.
2. Call **printPost** in the **loopComments** for the 1st time.
3. Use **comments** in the **printPost** but not be defined in the **printPost** (it is defined in the call function **loopComments** outside **printPost**.)

So, the problem is:
You should use variable *$posts* in the **printPost**  **foreach** loop but not *$comments*.

Comment: I just solved it, I just integrated the secnd function in the first one!